# Using the Mac Pro integrated microphone in VirtualBox Windows XP Host?

Tags: mac, audio, virtualbox, microphone

Is it possible to use the integrated microphone that comes with the Mac Book Pro inside Virtual Box with Windows XP Host? Because I tried and the only thing I get is noise.

Answer (score 1):

Latest information I found about this topic is from September this year and it seems not to be possible:

> Sorry still no support for audio in on osx.
>   You might be able to use an external usb sound card for input but no guarantees at all.
>   Oh and then you must use the puel-version to get usb at all.